# Execute commands with custom intervals

Tags: java

I am looking for something that will allow my app to do the following:

- run exe 1;
- if has exe 2: run exe 2 after exe 1 in X seconds;
- if has exe 3: run exe 3 after exe 2 in X seconds;

and so on.

I was initially using a executor thread pool, but that's overkill for something like this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with Timer in java  (scheduleAtFixedRate/Runnable)

You can start them by your condition and put a delay(Exist in method scheduleAtFixedRate for example)

Hope that helps